# List in Salesforce

Tags: java, list, salesforce

I am getting an error message when I am executing the below code saying that variable `myList` is not found.

```
public class ListExample {
    List<Integer> myList=new List<Integer>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    public static void main() {
        System.debug(myList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will not compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code:

- The **syntax** `List<Integer> myList=new List<Integer>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` is **incorrect**. You cannot create a list like that. You should use one of the classes that implement [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) which is an interface, such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), etc. A correct syntax would be, for instance, `List<Integer> myList=new ArrayList<Integer>();`.
- Variable **`myList` is not static** and non-static fields cannot be acceded inside static methods.

See an [example of how to fix it](https://ideone.com/daRrw6) using [`Arrays#asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) inside a [Static Initialization Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html):

```
public class ListExample {
    static List<Integer> myList;
    static {
        myList= Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        // this would work too
        // myList = new ArrayList<>();
        // for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        //     myList.add(i);
        // }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(myList);         // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
}
```